# Выполнение on_failure в gitlab

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci

Как в гитлабе можно задать выполнение стадии, в случае фэйла предыдущей?

## Пример.

Я собираю сначала образ. Затем — запускаю тесты. При этом, если хотя бы одна из стадий завалилась, мне нужно удалить образ и остановить все контейнеры. Я могу воспользоваться `when: on_failure` и написать для каждой из двух стадий `clean`. Но тогда, если падение произойдёт на стадии `build`, будут выполняться и `clean build` и `clean test`. А хотелось бы, чтобы выполнился только `clean build`. Как решить эту задачу?

```yaml
clean build:
  stage: test
  when: on_failure
  script:
    - make docker-stop
    - make docker-clean

clean test:
  stage: clean test
  when: on_failure
  script:
    - make docker-stop
    - make docker-clean

build:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - make docker-run-full
    - make docker-build

test:
  stage: test
  when: on_success
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - make docker-run-full
    - make docker-run-test
    - make docker-stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Да вот так, просто выведите стадию очистки в отдельную стадию clean test, в ней напишите джобы с ожиданиями. А также clean build и clean test можно объединить в одну джобу, вот так:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - clean build # <---- эта стадия содержит джобы с when: on_failure

build:
  stage: build
  when: manual
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - make docker-run-full
    - make docker-build

test:
  stage: test
  when: on_success
  allow_failure: false
  script:
    - make docker-run-full
    - make docker-run-test
    - make docker-stop

clean build:
  stage: clean build # <---- здесь стадия вместо test должна быть clean test или clean build
  when: on_failure
  script:
    - make docker-stop
    - make docker-clean
```

P.S. называть стадию clean build только ради очистки билда - наверное не совсем корректно, ведь в стадии, которая следует за тестами, может быть и джоба с деплоем, и тогда стадию надо назвать соответствующе.